# spring 3 my converter is not used

Tags: spring

...but registered

Using Spring 3

I have two converters registered as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
   <beans:property name="converters">
      <beans:list>
      <beans:bean class="mypackage.CalendarToStringConverter" />
      <beans:bean class="mypackage.StringToCalendarConverter" />
   </beans:list>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

The converters look like this:

```
public class StringToCalendarConverter implements Converter< String, Calendar > {
   public Calendar convert( String value ) {
      return Calendar.getInstance();
   }
}

public class CalendarToStringConverter implements Converter< Calendar, String > {
   public String convert( Calendar arg0 ) {
      return "23.10.1985";
   }
}
```

The problem is that they are not used during conversion in post and get requests.
What am I doing wrong?
What do I havt to do to get this working?
THX!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `<mvc:annotation-driven>` and if so, are you pointing to conversionService in the `conversion-service` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the converters configuration that works for me.  The differences you might try changing:

- I pass in a set instead of a list. (setConverters takes a Set parameter)
- I use FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean instead of ConversionServiceFactoryBean.  (Should not matter)
- My converters are defined as top level beans and referenced. (Also should not matter)

Hopefully one of this will fix your problem.

> ```
> <util:set id="converters" >
>    <ref bean="userDao" />
>    <ref bean="orderDao" />
> <util:set>
>
> <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
>     <property name="converters" ref="converters"/>
> </bean>
> ```